# Wrong results for a Mini-Max Sum implementation in C

Tags: c

Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.

Example

arr[5] = [1,3,5,7,9]

The minimum sum is 1+3+5+7=16 and the maximum sum is 3+5+7+9=24. The function prints

16 24

...and the test0 and test1 works properly:

Test0

- Input (stdin)

  1 2 3 4 5
- Expected Output

  10 14

Test14

- Input (stdin)

  7 69 2 221 8974
- Expected Output

  299 9271

During the test case my code fail 10/15 test, for example:

Test2

- Input (stdin)

  396285104 573261094 759641832 819230764 364801279
- Expected Output

  2093989309 2548418794

Test10

- Input (stdin)

  501893267 649027153 379408215 452968170 487530619
- Expected Output

  1821800271 2091419209

Where and what could I have done wrong?

```
void swap(int *p1, int *p2){
    int tmp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = tmp;
}
void selectionSort(int *arr, int arr_count)
{
     int i, j, minIndex;
     for(i=0; i<arr_count;i++){
         minIndex = i;
         for(j=i+1; j<arr_count; j++){
             if(arr[j]<arr[minIndex]){
                 minIndex = j;
             }
         }
         
         swap(&arr[minIndex],&arr[i]);
     }

}
void miniMaxSum(int arr_count, int* arr) {
    
    int i;
    int max1=0, max2=0, genericSum=0;
    
    selectionSort(arr, arr_count);
    
    for(i=0; i<arr_count; i++){
        genericSum += arr[i];
    }
    max1 = genericSum - arr[0];
    max2 = genericSum - arr[arr_count-1];
    
    printf("%d %d", max2, max1);
    return;

}
```

Maybe the problem it's the type of the data, 'cause in the main arr is initialize as int but maybe it could be better using a long.

Comment: No need for sorting, swapping, ... – just sum up all five values then subtract from the total sum each value individually and remember minimal and maximal values, that's it – linear approach compared to O(n log(n)) with *optimal* sorting, O(n²) with selection sort.

Comment: Side note: Correct type for specifying array sizes is `size_t`, not `int`...

Comment: Your `genericSum` is overflowing the maximum `int` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
void miniMaxSum(int arr_count, int* arr)
{
    int i;
    long long int max1=0, max2=0, genericSum=0;
    
    selectionSort(arr, arr_count);
    
    for(i=0; i<arr_count; i++){
        genericSum += arr[i];
    }
    max1 = genericSum - arr[0];
    max2 = genericSum - arr[arr_count-1];
    
    printf("%lld %lld", max2, max1);
    return;
}
```

I just used `long long int` instead of `int` and, in `printf`, I have used `%lld` instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Aconcagua above, the problem is solved in O(n) time without using a sort routine. the following solution uses the Ada programming language.

```ada
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values
-- that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers.
-- Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single
-- line of two space-separated long integers.
--
--  Input Format
--
--  A single line of five space-separated integers.
--
--  Constraints
--
--  Each integer is in the inclusive range .
--  Output Format
--
--  Print two space-separated long integers denoting the respective
-- minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly
-- four of the five integers. (The output can be greater than a 32
-- bit integer.)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type Num_T is range 0 .. 10**11;
   package Nums_Io is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO (Num_T);
   use Nums_Io;

   Sum : Num_T := 0;
   Max : Num_T := 0;
   Min : Num_T := Num_T'Last;
   I   : Num_T;
begin
   for x in 1 .. 5 loop
      Get (I);
      Sum := Sum + I;
      Max := Num_T'Max (Max, I);
      Min := Num_T'Min (Min, I);
   end loop;

   Put (Item => Sum - Max, Width => 1);
   Put (" ");
   Put (Item => Sum - Min, Width => 1);
   New_Line;

end Main;
```

The problem defines the data range for the problem to be 0 through 10^11. The type Num_T is defined to correspond to that range.
The program reads in 5 values of type Num_T, sums the values read in, computes the minimum value and the maximum value, then prints the sum minus the maximum value followed by the sum minus the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is more optimized solution in C++.

```cpp
void miniMaxSum(vector<int> arr) {
    long int minS = 0;
    long int maxS = 0;
    
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++) {
      minS += min(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
      maxS += max(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
    }
    
    cout << minS << " " << maxS << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though i have used C# to solve but i think it is easiest to solve the logic.
The whole concept is Get the sum, find the min number subtract it from sum to get Max sum, same concept goes for Min sum.

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System;

class Result
{

    /*
     * Complete the 'miniMaxSum' function below.
     *
     * The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
     */

    public static void miniMaxSum(List<int> arr)
    {
        long sum=0;
        int max=0;
        int min=arr[0];
        for(int i=0; i<arr.Count; i++)
        {
            sum+=arr[i];
            
            if(arr[i]>max)
            {
                max=arr[i];
            }
            if(arr[i]<min)
            {
                min=arr[i];
            }
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Abs(sum-max)+" "+Math.Abs(sum-min));
    }

}

class Solution
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<int> arr = Console.ReadLine().TrimEnd().Split(' ').ToList().Select(arrTemp => Convert.ToInt32(arrTemp)).ToList();

        Result.miniMaxSum(arr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a problem here:

> ```
> for(i=0; i<arr_count; i++){
>     genericSum += arr[i];
> }
> ```

`genericSum` is an `int` value, and adding sufficiently many large values causes *overflow* when `INT_MAX` is exceeded.  Overflow of signed types is *undefined behaviour* in C, which means the program could do absolutely anything.

To avoid overflow, we could use `long long`, which is guaranteed to be able to represent values up to 2⁶³-1, for the accumulator.

Alternatively, if we're guaranteed that the result will be in the range of `int`, we could compute `genericSum` *without* the smallest and largest values, adding them in only at the end:

```
for (i=1; i<arr_count-1; ++i){ /* don't include first and last */
    genericSum += arr[i];
}
max1 = genericSum + arr[arr_count-1];
max2 = genericSum + arr[0];
```

---

Note that we don't need to *sort* the input array - we can find the minimum and maximum values without needing to do that.